# c# open HTTP session to a website using username and password without WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, http, session, authentication, forms

I need to create an `HTTP` session to a website using a username and password. The website is developed in PHP, and login is simple HTML `form` with submit. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the website, the code below should be a reasonable starting point.
Use HttpWebRequest to send the login form data in the expected encoding, by using a cookie container the login session should be saved for subsequent requests.

```
  CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(<login url>);
  request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
  request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```